# Radio Button while using in List builder

Tags: flutter

I faced problem of separating value of radio button . As I use multiple radio buttons in multiple list that i get from APi. so every time , when i select one radio button ,it selects all radio button of this type in all list.  for example: radio 1 = check , radio 2 = unchecked in list 1 and list 2. i select radio 1 of list 1 but both radio 1 of list 1 and list 2 selected.

```
    import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:progress_dialog/progress_dialog.dart';
import 'package:project40/Constants/APIConstants.dart';
import 'package:project40/Constants/styleConstant.dart';
import 'package:project40/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:project40/api/add_filter_api.dart';
import 'package:project40/provider/add_post_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:project40/Constants/globals.dart' as globals;

class FilterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FilterScreenState createState() => _FilterScreenState();
}

class _FilterScreenState extends State<FilterScreen> {
  var jsonData;
  //String filterVariable;
  int school_everyone = 0;
  bool all_Feed = true;
  AddPostProvider _addPostProvider;
  int length = 0;
  int v = 0;
  Future mySchools() async {
    print("test");
    //loading dialog appears
    ProgressDialog pr;
    pr = new ProgressDialog(context, showLogs: true);
    pr.style(
        progressWidget: Container(
          width: 50,
          child: Lottie.asset("assets/json/360-loader.json"),
        ),
        message: 'Please wait...');
    pr.show();

    //api link
    String url = baseURL + mySchoolURL;

    //getting user token
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = prefs.getString("token");
    print(token);

    //create post request
    http.Response response = await http.get(url, headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    }).catchError((e) => print(e));
    print('successs');
    pr.hide();
    if (response == null) {
      //appear dialog if any error will be occured
      Alert(
        context: context,
        title: "",
        type: AlertType.none,
        desc: "Something went wrong. Please try again",
        buttons: [
          DialogButton(
            child: Text(
              "OK",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              pr.hide();
            },
            width: 120,
          )
        ],
      ).show();
    } else {
      jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

      if (jsonData["status_code"] == 200) {
        print(jsonData);
        // if (all_Feed == true) {
        //   filterVariable = "All School";
        // }
        // print(filterVariable);
        pr.hide();
        //store the no of institutions
        length = jsonData["data"].length;
        setState(() {});
      } else {
        pr.hide();
        //if error occured
        Alert(
          context: context,
          type: AlertType.none,
          title: "",
          desc: jsonData["message"],
          buttons: [
            DialogButton(
              child: Text(
                "OK",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                pr.hide();
              },
              width: 120,
            )
          ],
        ).show();
      }
    }
    return jsonDecode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    mySchools();
    if (all_Feed == true) {
      school_everyone = 0;
    }
    if (school_everyone == 1) {
      all_Feed = false;
    }
    // if (all_Feed == false) {
    //   setState(() {
    //     selectedRadio(2);
    //   });
    // }
    // if (school_everyone == 1) {
    //   setState(() {
    //     all_school = 0;
    //   });
    // }
  }

  void selectedRadio(int value) {
    setState(() {
      all_Feed = false;
      school_everyone = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _addPostProvider = Provider.of<AddPostProvider>(context, listen: false);
    return Material(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        body: Stack(
          //alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),

                  ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 45),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          GestureDetector(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Feed Filter",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          Container(width: 32.0),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        thickness: 1,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
                          },
                          child: allFilter(
                              Checkbox(
                                  value: all_Feed,
                                  activeColor: Colors.black,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      all_Feed = value;
                                      if (all_Feed == true) {
                                        school_everyone = 0;
                                      } else {
                                        school_everyone = 1;
                                      }
                                    });
                                  }),
                              Text(
                                "All school",
                                style: DayMoodRobotoStyle.heading5c,
                              )),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: Container(
                                  child: schoolUseage(
                                      jsonData["data"][index]["institution"]
                                              ["name"] ??
                                          "",
                                      jsonData["data"][index]["institution"]
                                              ["none"] ??
                                          "",
                                      jsonData["data"][index]["institution"]
                                              ["_id"] ??
                                          "",
                                      jsonData["data"][index]["year"]["year"] ??
                                          "",
                                      jsonData["data"][index]["year"]["_id"] ??
                                          "",
                                      jsonData["data"][index]["program"] == null
                                          ? ""
                                          : jsonData["data"][index]["program"]
                                              ["title"],
                                      jsonData["data"][index]["program"] == null
                                          ? ""
                                          : jsonData["data"][index]["program"]
                                              ["_id"],
                                      index),
                                ),
                              );
                            }),
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () async {
                          // var response =
                          //     await GetFilterPostAPI().getFilterPostApi(
                          //   ids: globals.filterVariable,
                          // );
                          // print('add filter response$response');
                          // if (response['status_code'] == 200) {
                          //   _addPostProvider.addPostProgress = false;
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                              msg: 'Filter Add Successfully..');
                          //   _addPostProvider.addPostProgress = false;
                          // } else {
                          //   Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: response['message']);
                          //   _addPostProvider.addPostProgress = false;
                          // }
                        },
                        hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                        child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: 55.0,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 20,
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28.0),
                            color: const Color(0xff0188ba),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: const Color(0x333F51B5).withOpacity(0.2),
                                offset: Offset(0, 20),
                                blurRadius: 20,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            'Filter',
                            style: DayMoodRobotoStyle.heading5,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget schoolInfo(Radio icon, Expanded schoolname) {
    return Row(
      children: [icon, schoolname],
    );
  }

  Widget allFilter(Checkbox icon, Text schoolname) {
    return Row(
      children: [icon, schoolname],
    );
  }

  Widget schoolUseage(
      String schooolName,
      String school_id,
      String _id,
      String classOf,
      String classof_id,
      String department,
      String department_id,
      int index) {
    String s1 = index.toString();
    String s2 = school_everyone.toString();
    String s = s1 + s2;
    v = int.parse(s);
    return Column(
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
            child: Text(
              schooolName,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: all_Feed == true ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue,
                  fontSize: 17,
                  fontFamily: "Ubuntu",
                  letterSpacing: 0.17,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
          child: all_Feed == true
              ? IgnorePointer(
                  ignoring: true,
                  child: schoolInfo(
                      Radio(
                          activeColor: Colors.black,
                          value: null,
                          groupValue: index,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            selectedRadio(value);
                            globals.filterVariable =
                                "all_" + school_id + "program_" + _id;
                          }),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          "Everyone",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              letterSpacing: 0.17,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                        ),
                      )),
                )
              : schoolInfo(
                  Radio(
                      activeColor: Colors.black,
                      value: 1,
                      groupValue: v,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          // String s1 = index.toString();
                          // String s2 = value.toString();
                          // String s = s1 + s2;
                          // v = int.parse(s);
                          selectedRadio(value);
                          globals.filterVariable = "all_$_id";
                        });
                      }),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      "Everyone",
                      style: DayMoodRobotoStyle.heading5c,
                    ),
                  )),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
          child: all_Feed == true
              ? IgnorePointer(
                  child: schoolInfo(
                      Radio(
                          activeColor: Colors.black,
                          value: 2,
                          groupValue: school_everyone,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            selectedRadio(value);
                          }),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          "None",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              letterSpacing: 0.17,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                        ),
                      )),
                )
              : schoolInfo(
                  Radio(
                      activeColor: Colors.black,
                      value: 2,
                      groupValue: v,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          // String s1 = index.toString();
                          // String s2 = value.toString();
                          // String s = s1 + s2;
                          // v = int.parse(s);
                          selectedRadio(value);
                          globals.filterVariable = "none_" + _id;
                        });
                      }),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      "None",
                      style: DayMoodRobotoStyle.heading5c,
                    ),
                  )),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
          child: all_Feed == true
              ? IgnorePointer(
                  child: schoolInfo(
                    Radio(
                        activeColor: Colors.black,
                        value: 2,
                        groupValue: school_everyone,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          selectedRadio(value);
                        }),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        department + " Only",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
                            fontSize: 15,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            letterSpacing: 0.17,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                        maxLines: 2,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : schoolInfo(
                  Radio(
                      activeColor: Colors.black,
                      value: 3,
                      groupValue: v,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          // String s1 = index.toString();
                          // String s2 = value.toString();
                          // String s = s2 + s1;
                          // v = int.parse(s);

                          selectedRadio(value);
                          globals.filterVariable = "program_" + _id;
                        });
                      }),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      department + " Only",
                      style: DayMoodRobotoStyle.heading5c,
                      maxLines: 2,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
          child: all_Feed == true
              ? IgnorePointer(
                  child: schoolInfo(
                      Radio(
                          activeColor: Colors.black,
                          value: classof_id,
                          groupValue: school_id,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            selectedRadio(value);
                          }),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          "Class of " + classOf + " Only",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              letterSpacing: 0.17,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                        ),
                      )),
                )
              : schoolInfo(
                  Radio(
                      activeColor: Colors.black,
                      value: 4,
                      groupValue: v,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          // String s1 = index.toString();
                          // String s2 = value.toString();
                          // String s = s2 + s1;
                          // v = int.parse(s);
                          selectedRadio(value);
                          globals.filterVariable = "year_" + _id;
                          //classOf + "_" + school_id;
                        });
                      }),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      "Class of " + classOf + " Only",
                      style: DayMoodRobotoStyle.heading5c,
                    ),
                  )),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
          child: all_Feed == true
              ? IgnorePointer(
                  child: schoolInfo(
                      Radio(
                          activeColor: Colors.black,
                          value: all_Feed == true ? 0 : department_id,
                          groupValue: school_id,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            selectedRadio(value);
                          }),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          department + " - " + classOf,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              letterSpacing: 0.17,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                        ),
                      )),
                )
              : schoolInfo(
                  Radio(
                      activeColor: Colors.black,
                      value: 5,
                      groupValue: v,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          // String s1 = index.toString();
                          // String s2 = value.toString();
                          // String s = s2 + s1;
                          // v = int.parse(s);
                          selectedRadio(value);
                          globals.filterVariable = "programyear_" + _id;
                          //  department + classOf + "_" + school_id;
                        });
                      }),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      department + " - " + classOf,
                      style: DayMoodRobotoStyle.heading5c,
                    ),
                  )),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: post your code please. It probably the `groupValue` issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the minimum implementation of 2Radio button groups.

```
class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  int group1Value;
  int group2Value;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Radio"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          //Let suppose this is group 1
          Row(
            children: [
              Radio(
                value: 0,
                groupValue: group1Value,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    group1Value = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
              Expanded(child: Text("Radio1")),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Radio(
                value: 1,
                groupValue: group1Value,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    group1Value = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
              Expanded(child: Text("Radio2")),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Radio(
                value: 2,
                groupValue: group1Value,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    group1Value = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
              Expanded(child: Text("Radio3")),
            ],
          ),

          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Text(
            "Second Group",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.copyWith(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),

          //suppose this is group 2
          Row(
            children: [
              Radio(
                value: 0,
                groupValue: group2Value,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    group2Value = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
              Expanded(child: Text("Radio1")),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Radio(
                value: 1,
                groupValue: group2Value,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    group2Value = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
              Expanded(child: Text("Radio2")),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Radio(
                value: 2,
                groupValue: group2Value,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    group2Value = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
              Expanded(child: Text("Radio3")),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here are the results

[image: 2 groups of radio button]

Comment: Hello Taha Malik!